# Using properties file with Wicket 6.18 and Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, properties, wicket

I am using Eclipse Luna to create Web Applications with Wicket 6.18. After creating a project with Maven and the quickstart archetype, i import the Maven project into Eclipse (after running mvn eclipse:eclipse in the project folder). Works fine. I can create an application and also deploy it to a Wildfly appserver. Runs smooth.
Now i want to use properties file for a page in my project. So i placed a wicket:message tag in the HTML file HomePage.html and also created a file HomePage.properties.xml in the same directory with the relating key value pair. When running the application, i am getting the error message

Last cause: Property 'proptest' not found in property files. Markup: [markup = vfs:/opt/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/proptest.war/WEB-INF/classes/de/watz/HomePage.html
message goes here, index = 1, current = [Raw markup]]

i also tried the build in appserver to exclude Wildfly settings as a root cause. Same result. I put the properties file in nearby every directory of the WAR, but always the same result.

I googled and searched in stackoverflow but did not found a single hint regarding where to place a properties file or if a certain configuration is needed to use it. I had the idea that i have to put some lines into the WicketApplication but did not found anything relating.

And i am starting to feel like a stupid because no one else has this problem as it looks like. But even the Wicket documentation about internationalization does not include a hint regarding this, so i assume it is an Eclipse problem.

Any idea what my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

And while i became more and more crazy about this issue, i found out how to create properties files in Eclipse. I am quite sure this is not the best way how to do it, but it works and figures out that it is an Eclipse usage problem.

I created a file named HomePage.properties (no XML) in my project package folder where HomePage.html is located. Then Eclipse editor offered me to add properties (Add button on the right side of the editor window). The form allows to enter a key and its value. After commit the application is re-deployed and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application's log for InvalidPropertiesFormatException, maybe your properties file wasn't valid XML.